# Next js , rtk query with typescript - linux build error

Tags: reactjs, linux, typescript, next.js, rtk-query

I've Been Building NextJs + typescript and with rtk query, project on my Local Machine, with no errors, build is also running fine, I then deployed it on a Linux server there I tried to build I got a build error stating :

```
./components/common/Admin/ProductAccordion/ProductBox.ts:3:10
Type error: Module
'"Qstate/apis"' has no exported member
'useGetProductByCategoryQuery'
import { Box } from '@mui/material'; import React, { Fragment } from 'react'.
import { useGetProductByCategoryQuery } from '@state/apis';
import { useGetCategorywithProductCountQuery } from '@state/apis';
import ProductCard from ' . /ProductCard'
```

File useGetProductByCategoryQuery looks like this:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
```

```
export const ProductApi = createApi({
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: apiAddress }),
    tagTypes: ['Product', 'ProductById', 'Plant'],
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getProductByCategory: builder.query<
            ProductInter,
            { id: string; search: string | any; plant: string }
        >({
            query: ({ id, search, plant }) => ({
                url: `all-products/${id}`,
                params: {
                    search: search,
                    plant: plant,
                },
            }),
            transformResponse: (response: ProductInter, meta, arg) => response,
            // Pick out errors and prevent nested properties in a hook or selector
            transformErrorResponse: (
                response: { status: string | number },
                meta,
                arg
            ) => response.status,
            // providesTags: (result, error, id) => [{ type: 'Product', id }],
            providesTags: ['Product'],
                       }), 
                }),
         });
```

```
export const {
    useGetProductByCategoryQuery,
} = ProductApi;
```

File Structure:
root folder

- state

  - apis

    - productCategoryApi.ts

this is what my tsconfig.json looks like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": [
        "components/*"
      ],
      "@assets/*":[
        "assets/*"
      ],
      "@state/*":[
        "state/*"
      ]
    },
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx","."],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

I've tried several things :

1. Changed relative imports to Path Imports.
2. added Barrel exports and updated imports accordingly.
3. Updated state folder path in paths in ts Config.json. below is the thing:

```
"paths": {
      "@components/*": [
        "components/*"
      ],
      "@assets/*":[
        "assets/*"
      ],
      "@state/*":[
        "./state/*"
      ]
    },
```

Comment: This should not make a difference between Linux and other OSes (I've created RTK Query in Linux). My immediate thought is that both environments have different TypeScript versions and the Linux TS version might be older than TS 4.2?

Comment: Project's TypeScript version is already updated i.e. 4.9.5

Comment: Well, I've figured out, I've been changing filenames in my local machine which were not been pushed to git, so it took a while. after that I replaced all the file with the fresh files and build worked.

Comment: @VatsalSoni whenever you are trying to rename the folder always use 
"git mv oldffoldername newfoldername" this way git detects any changes.